# Uniform continuous and Hölder on dense subset is Hölder continuous

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

Let $x$ be real and uniformly continuous on a set $I$ and Hölder with exponent $\alpha$ and constant $a$ on a dense subset $A$ of $I$. Then $x$ is Hölder on $I$.

By density of $A$, there exists $(s_n),(t_n)$ with $s_n\to s$ and $t_n\to t$. As $x$ is uniformly continuous on I, we have
\begin{align*}
|x(s)-x(t)|&\leq |x(s)-x(s_n)|+|x(t)-x(t_n)|+|x(s_n)-x(t_n)| \\
&\leq |x(s)-x(s_n)|+|x(t)-x(t_n)|+a|s_n-t_n|^\alpha \\
&\to a|s-t|^\alpha ~(n\to \infty).
\end{align*}

Why do we need uniform continuity and not just continuity?

This is not the same as the other question. One about extension of a continuous function and the other about compactness of set. Do you even read

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Set of Hölder continuous functions is compact](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3365558/set-of-h%c3%b6lder-continuous-functions-is-compact)

Comment: Don't ask same question repeatedly., You have option to update your question if needed

Comment: Read the question. It has nothing to do with the other one